# What game is featured on Discord's background?

Tags: game-identification

I saw this on Discord's background. What game is that from?

[image]

Comment: That it, at best, a stylized piece of art depicting a game.  It is not actually from a game.

Comment: Discord is targeted directly at gamers.  Not much of a stretch

Comment: @Frank and what leads you to believe it's an art?

Comment: Because it's a wallpaper with Diablo 3's Barbarian, that's why.  That's not from the game itself, guaranteed.

Comment: Upon further reflection I've decided that mod-closing this question is not the way to go. I'll let users decide. I apologize for acting in haste.

Comment: @Frank `game-identification` doesn't need to be only screenshots of gameplay. There's several poster art and even box art (without text) questions asking what the game is. And some with only a textual description.

Comment: @Annan It doesn't, but that doesn't mean this is a good question.  If I had my way, we'd not allow any type of identification that wasn't directly from the game itself, and I'm not the only one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the full-size image:

[image: Image taken directly from discord's backgrounds]

And when you throw that to Google reverse image search, it gives out "Diablo 3 Wallpaper Barbarian" and results such as these:

[image: 2 examples of the images returned by google reverse image search, showing the diablo 3 logo on the wallpaper]

Also, @Chippies linked [this](https://wall.alphacoders.com/big.php?i=670496), so it's probably a fanart for the game [Diablo 3](https://eu.battle.net/d3/en/).